In Unity, when packaging an APK using a release build, the Android app gets stuck on the Unity splash screen
When I use the 'release' setting in the 'minify' settings under Player Settings in Unity to package an APK, the app remains stuck on the splash screen when attempting to open it on an Android device.
I don't know how to do that.

You're going to need to check the logs to see what's going on. Using adb logcat -s Unity for example. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-debugging-on-an-android-device.html and https://developer.android.com/tools/adb
